# Why do we need check if a custom gesture recognizer still tracks a UITouch object in touchesBegin(_:with:)

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

Here is a copy of the Listing 3 of Section "Processing Touch Events" of the documentation page called [Implementing a Continuous Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/implementing_a_continuous_gesture_recognizer)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
   if touches.count != 1 {
      self.state = .failed
   } 

   // Capture the first touch and store some information about it.
   if self.trackedTouch == nil {           // <-- Q: Should it not be nil anyway?
      if let firstTouch = touches.first {
         self.trackedTouch = firstTouch
         self.addSample(for: firstTouch)
         state = .began
      }
   } else {
      // Ignore all but the first touch.
      for touch in touches {               // <-- Q: We have already set the
         if touch != self.trackedTouch {   // <-- state to .failed, why do
            self.ignore(touch, for: event) // <-- we care about the other
         }                                 // <-- touches?
      }
   }
}
```

Here, I don't understand why we need to check whether `self.trackedTouch` is `nil` or not. As far as I know UIKit must call reset() every time we set the gesture recognizer state to `.recognized`.

Additionally, in the else clause, it ignores all the touches except the first one. However, at the top of the function body, we set the state to `.failed` anyway; why do we care about the rest of the touches?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the code is accounting for the case where multiple touches are enabled on a view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing anything. I agree with you on both points.

Out of interest, what custom behaviour do you need that is not covered by the existing `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses?

Comment: I want to create a drawing app, and similar to the motivation of this documentation, I want to embed the stroke collecting logic into the gesture recognizer to simplify the code architecture. Otherwise, I will need to use an UIPanGestureRecognizer and handle the stroke collecting logic somewhere outside of the gesture recognizer.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Please let us know if you ever find out the answers to your original questions. (Perhaps there's some interaction with the predicted/coalesced touch mechanisms that we haven't considered?)